Match shortest item in an OR relationship
Suppose I would like to highlight text after // as comments, but shall stop after a }, for example:
Some Text **//Some Comments**

Some Text **//Some Comments}** More Text

What I prepared in my syntax file is
syn match                           MyComment  "\v\/\/.*(\}|$){-}"
hi def link                         MyComment  GruvboxGray

, where I used {-} try to match the shortest content, but it does not work, still, everything after // are matched as comments, not interrupted by a }.
Is there a way to define the shortest match?

Your .* will gobble up everything. Try something like (untested): [^}]{-}

@Friedrich seems it's not working.... also, it shall be \} than } right?

I don't think (even in \v mode) that you need to escape } here

@D.BenKnoble mmm.. the \v "very magic" mode is a bit mysterious. I think in "very magic" mode, all ASCII characters except '0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning. However Friedrich's answer works without escaping }. But, if in syntax file I define syn match MyTest "\vxx\}" and syn match MyTest "\vyy}" , then hi def link MyTest  GruvboxRed, then in vi only xx} will be red, yy} won't. I'm confused.

AFAIK, only opening curlies need to be escaped depending on magicness and whether they start a multi or are a literal "{". Closing curlies can be escaped but the regex engine should be able to tell from the context.

Your pattern is almost right, there's really just a little bit of confusion with multi and escapes.
In your pattern, you want to match two slashes followed by anything and terminated by a closing curly brace or a newline.
You want the anything part to be non-greedy so you need to apply the non-greedy multi to it.
The middle part of your pattern should be .{-}.
The OR statement to either match a closing curly brace or end of line is simply (}|$)
As a finishing note, you already cleverly use " to delimit your pattern and need not escape the slashes in it.
See :help :syn-pattern.
Applying all this, your :syntax command becomes:
syn match MyComment "\v//.{-}(}|$)"

The same pattern without the very magic flag would have the same length.
I'd favor this one because it's closer to the defaults:
syn match MyComment "//.\{-}(}\|$)"


Thank you so much. it's nice to see a neat solution to a tricky issue.
